# Python. How can I duplicate a value from a in a dictionary and put this value to a key in another list

Tags: python

```
Dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, '
g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3,
'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10}

def getWordScore(word, n):

    values=SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES.values()

    try:
         if len(word)!=n:
             for i in values:
                i+=i
                i*len(word)
                return i
        else:

            if len(word)==n:

                for i in values:
                    i+=i
                    i*n
                    return i+50
            else:
                if word=='':
                    print('0')
    except TypeError:
        print("-2")

getWordScore('perfect',7)
```

I want to put the values in `'Dictionary'` into `'word'`. For example, if `'word'` is `'perfect'`,then I hope I can use a code to put `'3','1','1','4','1','3','1'` (which are values from the `'Dictionary'`)into word and calculate it in presented ways.

I can't come up with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to lookup all the scores and save them in a list:

```
word = 'perfect'
scores = [Dictionary[letter] for letter in word]
# scores is [3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1]

# get sum
sum(scores)
# 14
```